# Converting Etc/GMT date to local in PHP

Tags: php, time

How do I convert "2011-08-19 07:44:26 Etc/GMT" to a local timestamp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php):

```
$d = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s T", "2011-08-19 07:44:26 Etc/GMT");
echo $d->format("r"), "\n";
$d->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone("EST"));
echo $d->format("r"), "\n";
```

will output

```
Fri, 19 Aug 2011 07:44:26 +0000
Fri, 19 Aug 2011 03:44:26 -0400
```

There is a great book on the topic: [php|architect's Guide to Date and Time Programming](http://www.phparch.com/books/phparchitects-guide-to-date-and-time-programming/). Programming with date and time is a quite extensive topic.

Comment: Though don't forget DateTime is only available as of PHP5.3.  But it is probably the better way to go if PHP5.3 IS available.

Comment: @Nick `DateTime` is available since [`PHP 5.2`](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/datetime.construct.php). It is `DateTime::createFromFormat` available from `PHP 5.3`

Answer (score 0):

`strtotime` will convert the string to an integer timestamp, then `strftime` will format the integer timestamp as localtime.

Comment: strtotime() does not work for me with this timestamp. It just returns false.

Comment: If you know the timezone is always GMT, you could just truncate the timestamp after the seconds value? That should then work.

Answer (score 0):

```
$UTC_timezone = new DateTimeZone("GMT");
$date = new DateTime("2011-08-19 07:44:26",$UTC_timezone);
echo $date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");echo "<br/>";
$current_timezone = new DateTimeZone(date_default_timezone_get());
$date->setTimezone($current_timezone);
echo $date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");

$timestamp = $date->getTimestamp();
```

See [list of timezones](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.others.php), [`date_default_time_zone`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-get.php), [`DateTime::setTimezone`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php), [`DateTime::getTimestamp`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimestamp.php) for details

Answer (score 0):

You can use gmmktime to convert GMT time to UNIX timestamp:

int gmmktime ( [int hour [, int minute [, int second [, int month [, int day [, int year [, int is_dst]]]]]]] )

and then you can use date to get your local format.

```
$timestamp = gmmktime(7,44,26,8,19,2011);
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$timestamp);
```